# Adding http://www to url

Tags: php

How can I add `http://www` to url in an elegant way? I could do a few if statements, but I prefer something neat.

The idea is to create a function addHttpWWW that returns the following, for the inputs below:

```
google.com => http://www.google.com
http://www.google.com => http://www.google.com
www.google.com => http://www.google.com
http://google.com => http://www.google.com
```

Comment: Not all websites require (or, for that matter, work with) the `www` prefix. Adding it arbitrarily is not a good idea.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$url = preg_replace('#(?:http(s)?://)?(?:www\.)?(.+)#', 'http\1://www.\2', $url);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$input = "google.com";   //Or whatever you want.

$output = "http://www." + str_replace(array("http://www.", "http://", "www."), "", $input);
```

Comment: it doesn't work for the other inputs mentioned in the original question.

Answer (score -3):

if u use jquery in your page :
here is a solution to after ajax works you can have this:
remmeber its work for 1.7.2 version ;)

```
<input type="text" id="txt_url" />

//...............................................

$("body").on("keyup","#txt_url",function() {
    var el=document.getElementById('txt_url');
    el.onkeyup=function();
    var str=el.value;
    if(str=='') return;   
    if(str.indexOf('http://')==-1 && str.length >= 7)
        el.value='http://'+str;   
    }
});
```

Working solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/3uupV/

Comment: The question is tagged *php* and never mentions JavaScript

Comment: @JoeBehymer its good when we have ajax .to after ajax can load this script